# Microsoft Word: how to cross-reference an autonum field?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference, field-codes, survey

I'm writing a survey questionnaire and use autonum fields for the question numbers. Say the 12th question is "Q{autonum}. Cats or dogs?", which Word shows as

```
Q12. Cats or dogs?
```

Later on I need to refer back to it:

```
If Q12 = "Cats" then:
Q33. Why cats?
```

There are quite a lot of these references and updating them manually whenever questions are added or removed is time-consuming and error-prone. I can't work out how to use a cross-reference in this case however. When I try to create a cross-reference of type Numbered list (I realise the questions aren't formatted as Word's numbered lists but it seems the closest thing), the "For which numbered item" box is empty. I tried using SEQ for the question numbers but still got an empty list of things I could cross-reference to.

Is it possible to cross-reference to an autonum or similar field? If it isn't, is there a better way to do what I need to do than manually updating all the cross references?

Comment: Does [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1654610/how-can-you-make-cross-referenced-numbered-items-in-word-update-when-referen) help with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Assign a bookmark to the AutoNum field and reference that.

Here is a link to the [topic of Cross-References](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#crossreferences) in my page on Complex Documents. You would have to add the hyperlink to each such field and assign a name.

The AutoNum field is legacy technology from Word 95. You may want to consider using Automatic numbering attached to a paragraph style.

Such a question or answer style could be could be formatted the same as your body text.

This would be available in the Cross-Reference dialog without adding a bookmark manually.

See my answer here for information on setting up numbering attached to styles. [How to set up advanced numbering?](https://superuser.com/questions/1739629/how-to-deal-with-advanced-numbering-in-word/1739680#1739680)

See also [my sample document](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#question) tutorial with multiple choice questions and answers which uses such a list. The screenshot below came from that sample document.

[image: Screenshot of Cross-Reference Dialog]